# NavLink isActive with multiple paths to same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have two paths (`"/"` and `"/home"`) that render the same component:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <ContentWrapper />,
    errorElement: <p>404</p>,
    children: [
      { path: "", element: <Home /> },
      { path: "home", element: <Home /> },
    ]
  }
])
```

Is it possible to get `isActive=true` from `NavLink` for both `exaple.com` and `exaple.com/home`?

```
<div>
  <NavLink to="/home" className={({ isActive }) => ( isActive ? ... : ...>
    Home
  </NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/projects" className={({ isActive }) => ( isActive ? ... : ...>
    Projects
  </NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/about" className={({ isActive }) => ( isActive ? ... : ...>
    About
  </NavLink>
</div>
```

Right now `<Home />` component gets rendered in both `"/"` and `"/home"` paths, the only problem is the menu, Home `NavLink` has active CSS only when the path is `"/home"`.

If it is not possible, can I always redirect from `"/"` to `"/home"` from the `BrowserRouter` (without using a custom empty component with an effect to call redirect `function`)?

I'd like to give a simple link like `"https://example.com"` and not `"https://exaple.com/home"`, but I'd like to keep the `"/home"` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll get what you want without creating your own custom path matching logic. A `"/home"` path will match any `"/home/*"` path, but exclude `"/"` from matching, and using path `"/"` will match any path, and using `"/"` with the `end` prop will match `"/"` exactly and exclude `"/home"`.

> If it is not possible, can I always redirect from `"/"` to `"/home"` from the
> `BrowserRouter` (without using a custom empty component with an effect
> to call redirect function)?

Yes, this is possible. Redirecting from `"/"` to `"/home"`, or vice versa, so there is only one route rendering `Home` so the link can match is my suggestion.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <ContentWrapper />,
    errorElement: <p>404</p>,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Navigate to="/home" replace /> },
      { path: "home", element: <Home /> },
    ]
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that if you only want to get the custom style when either path is active you can do the following:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function Mycomponent() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    <NavLink to='/home' className={({ isActive }) => isActive || pathname === '/' ? 'navbar-item active' : 'navbar-item' }>
        <p>Home</p>
    </NavLink>

}
```

Since the isActive will return true for "/home" you just need to check if the path name is "/", if yes then you return true.

You can also use this method for more paths, like so:

```
isActive || ["/path1", "/path2", "/path3"].includes(pathname)
```